# How to test if string ends with a list of string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ends-with

I have an array of string and another string, Is there a simple way to test if my single string ends with one of the strings in the array of strings?

```js
const strings = [
  'foo',
  'bar',
  'test'
];

if ('hi, this is a test'.endsWith(...strings)) { // I know that this isn't right but this is the idea
  console.log("String ends with one of the strings !");
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about `Array.prototype.some()`?

```
if (strings.some(s => 'hi, this is a test'.endsWith(s))) {...}
```